# Python: String formatting to the right side

Tags: python, string, formatting, string-formatting

Here is my source code:

```
def fibonacci_numbers():
  how_many_numbers = int(input("\nHow many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: "))
  i = 0
  res = [0, 1]
  while i < how_many_numbers:
      res.append(sum(res[-2:]))
      print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, res[i]))
      i += 1


fibonacci_numbers()
```

The output now is:

```
How many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: 30
1. 0
2. 1
3. 1
4. 2
5. 3
6. 5
7. 8
8. 13
9. 21
10. 34
11. 55
12. 89
13. 144
...
30. 514229
```

But I need something like that:

```
How many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: 30
1.       0
2.       1
3.       1
4.       2
5.       3
6.       5
7.       8 
8.      13
9.      21
10.     34
11.     55
12.     89
13.    144
...
30. 514229
```

and so on. It's depending for a numbers I choose. If i take 50 numbers so I need more spaces, but everything need to be placed to the right side.

How I can achieve this?

I tried with `{:>width}` and with `.rjust` method, but I can't get it.

Is there simple solution for that?

Or maybe I need make another loop and print there?

***Final Solution:***

Thanks for answers. I pick up some of them and i made this:

```
def fibonacci_numbers():

    how_many_numbers = int(input("\nHow many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: "))
    i = 0
    res = [0, 1]
    while i < how_many_numbers:
        res.append(sum(res[-2:]))
        i += 1

    size_of_i = len(str(i))
    i = 0
    for num in res[:-1]:
        size = len(str(res[-2]))
        print("{:<{width_of_i}} {:>{width}}".format(str(i)+":", num, width_of_i=size_of_i + 1, width=size))
        i += 1



fibonacci_numbers()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to format both values:

```
import math

def fibonacci_numbers():
  how_many_numbers = int(input("\nHow many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: "))
  i = 0
  res = [0, 1]
  for i in range(how_many_numbers):
      res.append(sum(res[-2:]))
  digits = int(math.log10(res[i]))+1
  ind_digits = int(math.log10(how_many_numbers-1))+2
  for i in range(how_many_numbers):
      print("{:<{ind_digits}} {:>{digits}}".format("{}.".format(i + 1), res[i], ind_digits=ind_digits, digits=digits))


fibonacci_numbers()
```

**UPD:** support fo variable length added.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: @patruk91, please consider upvoting my answer :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation now to cast vote, but I will do that when I get it. I promise! :). I marked it as the most helpful one! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your print statement to this

```
print("{}. {:10}".format(i + 1, res[i])) # for left justify
print("{}. {:>10}".format(i + 1, res[i])) # for right justify
```

If you need more information on how to do it, refer to this [link](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Is not what I mean, because if Fibonacci number will be more than 10 char the stairs will start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format-string to justify to the right. Try this for your print:

```
print("{}. {:>20}".format(i + 1, res[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
def fibonacci_numbers():
how_many_numbers = int(input("\nHow many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: "))
i = 0
res = [0, 1]
while i < how_many_numbers:
    res.append(sum(res[-2:]))
    print("{}. \t\t{}".format(i + 1, res[i]))
    i += 1


fibonacci_numbers()
```

Comment: I don't think this will yield what the OP is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not know how many digits the last number has, you have to store the results in a list and then add spaces while printing.

For example get the length of last number as a string

```
size = len(str(numbers[-1])))
padding = ""
for i in range(size):
    padding += " "
```

and then loop through the array adding the needed spaces:

```
for num in numbers:
    print(padding[len(str(num)):] + str(num))
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify formatting width to align it to the right correctly.

Code:

```
def fibonacci_numbers(format_width):
  how_many_numbers = int(input("\nHow many Fibbonacci numbers you want print: "))
  i = 0
  res = [0, 1]
  while i < how_many_numbers:
      res.append(sum(res[-2:]))
      # Here we specify alignment to right with certain width 
      # which is >= number of digits of the largest integer in your sequence.:
      print("{}. {:>{width}}".format(i + 1, res[i], width=format_width)) 
      i += 1


fibonacci_numbers(30)
```